# How to extract link url from Excel cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, dataset, exceldatareader

I have a c# webjob that downloads and then reads an Excel file.  One of the columns contains links that I'd like to save in my database.  I'm currently using ExcelDataReader to convert the Excel file to a DataSet and then looping through the rows to grab the data.  After conversion the column in question at this point is only a string containing the link text.

From some other reading it sounds like in Excel, hyperlinks are stored elsewhere and that information isn't preserved when converting the Excel file to a DataSet.

I'm not set on using ExcelDataReader but would like to find a solution to extract these link URLs without having to pay for some third part software.

Here is the simple code I have so far as reference:

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

int count = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in result.Tables["WorkSheetName"].DataTable.Rows)
{
    var item = new myObject();

    item.Prop1 = long.Parse(row["Column3"].ToString());
    item.Prop2 = row["Column7"].ToString(); //The link, currently only seeing link text

    this.myDbContext.myTable.Add(item);
    await this.myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    count += 1;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, You have a string and you want to convert that to a URL?

Comment: In the Excel file it is a hyperlink.  When reading the cell as a string it only extracts the link text and not the URL that the link leads to.

Comment: In VBA, the address property of the hyperlink attached to the cell would return the URL.  The hyperlink object attached to the cell would be the first item in the Hyperlinks collection.  So in VBA, it would look something like `Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).address` for the URL.  Can you do something similar in C#?

Comment: Ron, looks like I just needed to use a plugin that gave me access to that data, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up being able to get the hyperlink data using EPPLUS to read my excel file.

Code:

```
var pck = new ExcelPackage(excelFileStream);
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

DataTable dt = new DataTable(ws.Name);
int totalCols = ws.Dimension.End.Column;
int totalRows = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
int startRow = 3;
ExcelRange wsRow;
DataRow dr;
foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[2, 1, 2, totalCols])
{
    dt.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
}

for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= totalRows; rowNum++)
{
    wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, totalCols];
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    int rowCnt = 0;
    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
    {
        if (rowCnt == 7)
        {
            if (cell.Hyperlink != null)
            {
                dr[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Hyperlink.AbsoluteUri;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dr[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
        }

        rowCnt++;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr[7].ToString()))
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}

return dt;
```